# Can't infer lifetimes when using Ref::map with trait objects

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a struct `A` with boxed trait (`Foo`), a another struct `BoxedA` which has a `Rc<RefCell<A>>` in it. I'm trying to create a method on `BoxedA` that returns refrence to boxed trait, but keep running into problems with lifetimes when mapping `Ref<A>` to `Ref<Foo>`.

Here's my code:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref};

trait Foo {

}

struct A {
    a: Box<Foo>
}

impl A {
    fn new(a: Box<Foo>) -> A {
        A { a: a }
    }

    fn a(&self) -> &Foo {
        &*self.a
    }
}

struct BoxedA {
    a: Rc<RefCell<A>>
}

impl BoxedA {
    fn new(a: Box<Foo>) -> BoxedA {
        BoxedA {
            a: Rc::new(RefCell::new(A::new(a)))
        }
    }

    fn a(&self) -> Ref<Foo> {
        Ref::map(self.a.borrow(), |a| a.a())
    }
}

impl Foo for i32 {

}

fn main() {
    let a = BoxedA::new(Box::new(3));

    let a_ref = a.a();
}
```

Rust playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d0348ad9b06a152770f3877864b01531&version=stable&backtrace=0

I get following compilation errors:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to      conflicting requirements
  --> <anon>:34:41
   |
34 |         Ref::map(self.a.borrow(), |a| a.a())
   |                                         ^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 34:38...
  --> <anon>:34:39
   |
34 |         Ref::map(self.a.borrow(), |a| a.a())
   |                                       ^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> <anon>:34:39
   |
34 |         Ref::map(self.a.borrow(), |a| a.a())
   |                                       ^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 33:28...
  --> <anon>:33:29
   |
33 |       fn a(&self) -> Ref<Foo> {
   |  _____________________________^ starting here...
34 | |         Ref::map(self.a.borrow(), |a| a.a())
35 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here
note: ...so that the declared lifetime parameter bounds are satisfied
  --> <anon>:34:9
   |
34 |         Ref::map(self.a.borrow(), |a| a.a())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Oddly enough, code compiles if i replace all `Foo`'s with `i32`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this signature:

```
fn a(&self) -> &Foo { ... }
```

By the lifetime elision rules, this expands to:

```
fn a<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b (Foo + 'b) { ... }
```

Whoa, what's that `+ 'b` bit?

Trait objects have a lifetime bound that specifies the shortest lifetime of the references contained in the object. If the type doesn't contain any references, that lifetime bound will be `'static`.

If you implement the trait on a type that contains references, for example a pair of references:

```
impl<'a, 'b> Foo for (&'a u32, &'b u32) {}
```

then you have a variable of type `&Foo` that happens to be a reference to a `(&'a u32, &'b u32)` (to be clear, that's a reference to a pair of references), where did the lifetime information about the two `&u32` references go? That's where the lifetime bound on the trait object comes in. The full expanded type of `&Foo` will look like `&'c (Foo + 'd)`, where `'d` is the shortest of `'a` and `'b` (or possibly even shorter, thanks to covariance).

There are many other places where you didn't specify a lifetime bound explicitly. All places *expect the return type of a function* will default to a `'static` lifetime bound. That's what happens, for example, to the `Box<Foo>` in `struct A`: it's actually interpreted as `Box<Foo + 'static>`.

---

The easy solution to your problem is to specify that `A::a` returns a trait object with a `'static` lifetime bound:

```
fn a(&self) -> &(Foo + 'static) { ... }
```

This makes a lot of sense, because we are returning a pointer to the interior of a `Box<Foo + 'static>`!

`BoxedA::a` might eventually cause you similar issues, so you might want to fix this one too while you're at it:

```
fn a(&self) -> Ref<Foo + 'static> { ... }
```

---

Now that you're aware of these lifetime bounds, you might want to consider whether it makes sense to make `A` and `BoxedA` generic over that lifetime bound, instead of enforcing `'static`. If you want to maximize genericity, your code would look like this:

```
struct A<'a> {
    a: Box<Foo + 'a>
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    fn new(a: Box<Foo + 'a>) -> A<'a> {
        A { a: a }
    }

    fn a(&self) -> &(Foo + 'a) {
        &*self.a
    }
}

struct BoxedA<'a> {
    a: Rc<RefCell<A<'a>>>
}

impl<'a> BoxedA<'a> {
    fn new(a: Box<Foo + 'a>) -> BoxedA<'a> {
        BoxedA {
            a: Rc::new(RefCell::new(A::new(a)))
        }
    }

    fn a(&self) -> Ref<Foo + 'a> {
        Ref::map(self.a.borrow(), |a| a.a())
    }
}
```

It's up to you to decide if you need this level of genericity or not.